# remove html tag id after clone appendchild

Tags: jquery

im trying to remove an id after it is cloned and its not working i have this:

head:

```
    $(window).load(function() {
          $('#datepicker-example7-start').Zebra_DatePicker({
             direction: false,
             pair: $('#datepicker-example7-end')
        });

        $('#datepicker-example7-end').Zebra_DatePicker({
            direction: true
          });
      });
```

body:

```
<input id="datepicker-example7-start" class="dp-start" type="text" name="datefrom[]" style="width:100%" />

<input id="datepicker-example7-end" class="dp-end" type="text"  name="dateto[]" style="width:100%"/>
```

and my jquery clone is:

```
   var elements, templateRow, rowCount, row, className, newRow, element;
var i, s, t;

/* Get and count all "tr" elements with class="row".    The last one will
 * be serve as a template. */

if (!document.getElementsByTagName)
    return false; /* DOM not supported */
elements = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
templateRow = null;
rowCount = 0;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    row = elements.item(i);

    /* Get the "class" attribute of the row. */
    className = null;
    if (row.getAttribute)
        className = row.getAttribute('class');
    if (className === null && row.attributes) {    // MSIE 5
        /* getAttribute('class') always returns null on MSIE 5, and
         * row.attributes doesn't work on Firefox 1.0.    Go figure. */
        className = row.attributes['class'];
        if (className && typeof(className) === 'object' && className.value) {
            // MSIE 6
            className = className.value;
        }
    } 

    /* This is not one of the rows we're looking for.    Move along. */
    if (className !== "row_to_clone_fw_emp")
        continue;

    /* This *is* a row we're looking for. */
    templateRow = row;
    rowCount++;
}
if (templateRow === null)
    return false; /* Couldn't find a template row. */

/* Make a copy of the template row */
newRow = templateRow.cloneNode(true);

/* Change the form variables e.g. price[x] -> price[rowCount] */
elements = newRow.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    element = elements.item(i);
    s = null;
    s = element.getAttribute("name");
    if (s === null)
        continue;
    t = s.split("[");
    if (t.length < 2)
        continue;
    s = t[0] + "[" + rowCount.toString() + "]";
    element.setAttribute("name", s);
    element.value = "";
   /* element.find('#datepicker-example7-start').removeAttr('id'); 
    element.find('#datepicker-example7-end').removeAttr('id'); */
}



templateRow.parentNode.appendChild(newRow);

$('.dp-start:last').Zebra_DatePicker({
     direction: false,
     pair: $('.dp-end:last')
});

$('.dp-end:last').Zebra_DatePicker({
     direction: true
});

return true;
```

i have tried placing this after calling the datepicker on head and before calling it again on clone method but aint working:

```
    $('input#datepicker-example7-start').RemoveAttr('id');
    $('input#datepicker-example7-end').RemoveAttr('id');
```

and

```
    $('input.dp-start:last').RemoveAttr('id');
    $('input.dp-end:last').RemoveAttr('id');
```

what i need is to remove the id after calling the datepicker on head tag so that when i click add row submit button and call the clone method it will not clone the input tags with id and will not load the calendar icon again... it seems that the calendar icon is overlapping every clone which made it not clickable and calendar loads only if textbox is clicked (1st row, both textbox and calendar icon is clickable)

thanks for help!

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. It's `removeAttr`, not `RemoveAttr`.

Comment: It always helps to check the console, too. You'll probably be thrown an error, like the method 'RemoveAttr' does not exist or the likes.

Comment: already change to lowercase, still not working

Comment: i tried this also and it didn't work newRow = templateRow.cloneNode(true).removeAttr('id');

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question very well but try if your just trying to remove the id try this

```
 $('input.dp-start:last').attr("id","");
```

or

```
 $('input.dp-start:last').removeAttr('id');
```

Comment: the scenario is this, i have a cloned rows wherein that two input fields calls a function onload thru the id... what i need is not to load the id on the cloned rows so that it will not call the function again thanks @swsa

Comment: Okay if you could maybe make me a jsfiddle of your code I can help you out no problem because it could be something else in your code that is making it not work since the syntax is correct

Comment: another assumption is that maybe the id calls the css again after clone that's why it displays the icon that should not be displayed

Comment: I can't really tell without viewing the code for myself if you need more detailed help I can give you my email

Comment: here it is @swsa [http://jsfiddle.net/jakecruz011/ZvsZm/2/] it may not run coz the plugin external resources cannot be uploaded all

Comment: both links are down for some reason

Comment: i am actually viewing it now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39957/discussion-between-jake-and-swsa)